# How to prevent ’ character being entered into a textbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, regex, apostrophe

I am trying to prevent the `’` character from being entered into a textbox. 
The problem is if you copy and paste the `’` character it becomes a right single quotation, which causes an error in the sql when trying to save the textbox to the database.

You can see this here in the
[unicode lookup](http://unicodelookup.com/#%E2%80%99/1)

If you manually enter in `'` then it is an apostrophe and this character is accepted.

The problem is people are copying and pasting this character from emails into the textbox and it gets converted to the single right quote.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
Match match = regex.Match(txtName.Text);
if (!match.Success)
{
     DisplayMsg("Name contains invalid character");
}
```

Is there a way to still allow the user to enter an apostrophe but prevent the single right quotation?

Comment: How does a right apostrophe cause a SQL error when a "regular" apostrophe does not?

Comment: @DStanley if you click the link for the unicode lookup and enter in `’` it becomes a single right quotation. It will only happens if I copy the apostrophe from something like for example an email. The single right quotation then causes an sql error.

Comment: But a single apostrophe works?  Or are you concatenating strings and an apostrophe causes an error?  If that's the problem then fix _that_ by using parameters instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: yes a single apostrophe works.

Comment: But _what is the error_?  I don't get how a right quotation can cause an error unless you're doing some sort of string manipulation which can probably be fixed.

Comment: No amount of filtering is going to save you from SQL injection attacks, simply because the problem isn't the input. You need to use parameterized queries or an ORM. The resulting code will be simpler, faster and far more secure

Comment: @DStanley I am using parameters like `Name = ?Name,`. It is just sql has a problem with that character. It cuts off the sql statement for example if I tried `Bernard O’Toole` so I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Toole',

Comment: How are you storing that text into your database? Please add that code - the problem may be there. See also http://bobby-tables.com/about.html

Comment: @user123456789 Please post the database access code. Are you sure you don't have a *codepage* problem? What is the field's codepage? With parameterized queries the *driver* passes the data directly to the server, it's never included in the query itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than preventing users from entering (especially if they are copying and pasting), you'd be better off replacing the character yourself if you really need to get rid of it:

```
txtName.Text = txtName.Text
    .Replace((char) 0x2018, '\'')  // &lsquo; ‘
    .Replace((char) 0x2019, '\'')  // &rsquo; ’
    .Replace((char) 0x201C, '"')   // &ldquo; “
    .Replace((char) 0x201D, '"');  // &rdquo; ”
```

This way, you won't get in the way of your users and you'll still remove this character.

However, it does sound like you might be building up queries using string concatenation, and this is a more serious problem!

Comment: Seeing the comments, it appears the OP has an encoding problem, unrelated either to input or string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

<s>Is it possible to just encode the strings using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("A string with lot's of q'o'u't'e's that should work f'i'n'e'")` which results in `A string with lot&#39;s of q&#39;o&#39;u&#39;t&#39;e&#39;s that should work f&#39;i&#39;n&#39;e&#39;`...</s>

Since I can't comment on anyone else's answers other than my own, I have to do it like this.

Building off of the solution from @Richard, it could be made a little more readable for others that will have to follow after you.

```
string someString = "This has a left quote: ’\nThis has a right quote: ‘";

string sanitized = someString.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&lsquo;"), "'")
                                 .Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&rsquo;"), "'");
Console.WriteLine(sanitized);
```

Edit: Misunderstood the original intent.

Comment: The OP needs to convert _from_ `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` _to_ apostrophe.